# MYSQL SELECT NOT RETURNING CERTAIN RESULTS

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php script which selects from a MySQL table. The Table Content is set to UTF8, so is the php script interfacing with it.

The input strings are real_escaped. I am facing the following issue:
Given the following data in the table:

- ID Username
- 1  Test
- 2  Test1
- 3  Test-A

---

The following SQL returns the IDs for 1 and 2 **successfully** but when asked for the 3rd it returns nothing.

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `User` WHERE `Username` = '$User'
```

Why is it not returning when I ask for the ID where Username = **Test-A**? 
Is it because the Username contains a minus?

Comment: I would be cautious about mysql injection. Look into prepared statements.

Comment: Does that solve my problem with the third test case too?

Comment: No, querying isn't affected just because there is a - in the string.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a different string. Double check the dash/hyphen mark in both cases (may be different unicode characters like described [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm)) - it happens frequently when copying and pasting data from "rich" text editors.
Also check for whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "real_escaped" it might be the case that your username is escaped turning into something similar to ('Test\-A') which essentially does not exist.

Print out the value of the $User to check what you're sending to MySQL.

On top of that, you are using old outdated practices, there are better ways of querying the database securely with PDO::prepare (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), use those examples there.